# Store weekdays and time of the day table in database

Tags: database

I have the following data (this is not a real table in database, it's just a group of information I need to store with each post in my database):

```
X = yes / true
O = no  / false

Weekday   | Morning | Day | Evening | Night |
---------------------------------------------
Monday    |    X    |  O  |    O    |   X   |
Tuesday   |    X    |  O  |    O    |   X   |
Wednesday |    O    |  O  |    X    |   X   |
Thursday  |    O    |  X  |    O    |   O   |
Friday    |    X    |  X  |    X    |   X   |
Saturday  |    O    |  O  |    X    |   O   |
Sunday    |    X    |  X  |    X    |   O   |
```

How should I store data like this in a database? Im not too experienced with database design and all the possible ways I could think of waste a lot of space. Normalization is not a requirement for this.

I don't need to query by this data, I just need to store it efficiently in parent object/entity.

Comment: At first glance, I'm thinking replacing the `Weekday` column with a `datetime`.  It is always possible to figure out the weekday from the date.

Comment: Your question is far from clear... What do you mean by "_I have lots of these_"?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, as suggested in my previous comment, it is not clear if the need is only for weekday or not. If yes, what's the point of storing actual dates at all?

Comment: @FDavidov I mean that this (my drawn table in question) is not a table in database, it's a group of information I need to store with each post in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said, I'd create a table with 4 columns (Morning, Day, Evening, Night) and a Primary Key to reference the individual datasets (like the one you've shown). Then I'd use a [bitfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) for each row entry. For example Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 4, Thurs = 8, Friday = 16, Saturday = 32, and Sunday = 64.

Your dataset provided (here as PK 001) could be saved in a single row as:

```
 
 PK       | Morning | Day | Evening | Night |
001          83        88    116       23
```

The morning value is 83, because Monday (1) + Tues (2) + Friday (16) + Sunday (64) = 83.

You'd only need to use a datatype that can store a 128-bit number max. This depends on which database you use but many databases have a binary(64) type that would work.

You would then use the bitwise & operator to test if a day is represented by a particular value:

83 (Morning Value) & 16 (Friday) = 16 (Friday, therefore true)
88 (Day value) & 4 (Wednesday) = 0 (therefore false)
116 (Evening value) & 32 (Saturday) = 32 (Saturday, therefor true)

Alternatively, you could create a bitfield column for each Day of the Week, and the value would be Morning = 1, Day = 2, Evening = 4, and Night = 8.

Your given dataset would be represented as a single row in the database as:

```
 PK   | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
 001     9     9     12    2     15    4     7
```

Answer (score 0):

You may think of creating a table with 28 columns, being each group of 4 columns corresponding to the 4 *times* of each day. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE <name> ( SUNDAY_MORNING VARCHAR(1) ,
                      SUNDAY_DAY     VARCHAR(1) ,
                      SUNDAY_EVENING VARCHAR(1) ,
                      SUNDAY_NIGHT   VARCHAR(1) ,
                      MONDAY_MORNING VARCHAR(1) ,
                      MONDAY_DAY     VARCHAR(1) ,
                      MONDAY_EVENING VARCHAR(1) ,
                      MONDAY_NIGHT   VARCHAR(1) ,
                      ...
                    ) ;
```

Of course, KEYs may need to be defined, but it is not possible to suggest anything based on the provided info.

As per your concern of SPACE, this structure will se MUCH LESS space than you can imagine.